# RRDTool graph command insert into variable

Tags: shell, rrdtool

I am using sh(1) shell script to generate RRDTool for day, week, month and year. My question is, how to make this code more effective without repeating the same code? I tried it like this but always get errors, use trailing escape character etc:

```
NEWVAR="-a PNG -v "Interrupts/s" -h 130 -w 576 \
    --watermark "`hostname`:`date "+%H:%M:%S - %d/%m/%Y"`" --font TITLE:15: \
    --font LEGEND:7: --font UNIT:7: --font AXIS:5: -c CANVAS#000000 -c BACK#D8D8D8 \
    DEF:DI="$RRDFDI":DI:AVERAGE \
    CDEF:DIx=DI,8000,LT,DI,UNKN,IF \
    AREA:DIx#FFDD44:"" \
    LINE1.2:DIx#31B404:"Device Interrupts" \
    GPRINT:DIx:MIN:"Min\:%6.0lf" \
    GPRINT:DIx:AVERAGE:"Avg\:%6.0lf" \
    GPRINT:DIx:MAX:"Max\:%6.0lf" \
    GPRINT:DIx:LAST:"Cur\:%6.0lf\l""

$RRDBIN graph $NEWVAR -t "Device Interrupts Days Statistic (Interrupts)" --start -1d
$RRDBIN graph $NEWVAR -t "Device Interrupts Weeks Statistic (Interrupts)" --start -1w 
$RRDBIN graph $NEWVAR -t "Device Interrupts Months Statistic (Interrupts)" --start -1m 
$RRDBIN graph $NEWVAR -t "Device Interrupts Years Statistic (Interrupts)" --start -1y
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: effective in what since ? That is faster? That is more readable? define effective please. Also what OS is it?

Comment: I mean, effective for avoid repeat the same code ($NEWVAR). I use FreeBSD. Thank

Comment: FreeBSD, +1 for that. To avoid repetition you should try loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, something along the lines of following.

```
NEWVAR="-a PNG -v "Interrupts/s" -h 130 -w 576 \
  --watermark "`hostname`:`date "+%H:%M:%S - %d/%m/%Y"`" --font TITLE:15: \
  --font LEGEND:7: --font UNIT:7: --font AXIS:5: -c CANVAS#000000 -c BACK#D8D8D8 \
  DEF:DI="$RRDFDI":DI:AVERAGE \
  CDEF:DIx=DI,8000,LT,DI,UNKN,IF \
  AREA:DIx#FFDD44:"" \
  LINE1.2:DIx#31B404:"Device Interrupts" \
  GPRINT:DIx:MIN:"Min\:%6.0lf" \
  GPRINT:DIx:AVERAGE:"Avg\:%6.0lf" \
  GPRINT:DIx:MAX:"Max\:%6.0lf" \
  GPRINT:DIx:LAST:"Cur\:%6.0lf\l""

for c in d w m y ; do
  $RRDBIN graph $NEWVAR -t "Device Interrupts Days Statistic (Interrupts)" --start -1$c output.file.$c
done
```

Comment: But I still got error: Interrupts         GPRINT:DIx:MIN:Min:%6.0lf         GPRINT:DIx:AVERAGE:Avg:%6.0lf         GPRINT:DIx:MAX:Max:%6.0lf         GPRINT:DIx:LAST:Cur:%6.0lfl: not found
ERROR: missing filename

Comment: Well, obviously I have no idea what your `$RRDBIN` expects, so you should provide an example of the whole command in your question. Edited the answer to reflect a best guess for what your command might expect.

Comment: IMHO, is code with the same lines don't need rewrite again, so I need insert (The same code) to variable. I just need changes -t, IMGPATH, --start options.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious reason for your errors when using this code is that you have failed to escape the embedded double quotes in your declaration of `NEWVAR`.

You cannot generate all three graphs simulataneously; the way you are coding it is optimal, though you need to fix your use of embedded quotes in the NEWVAR declaration.  You will also need to double-escape the colons and \l endof line sequence...

> NEWVAR="-a PNG -v \"Interrupts/s\" -h 130 -w 576 \
>     --watermark \""`hostname`":"`date '+%H:%M:%S - %d/%m/%Y'`"\" --font TITLE:15: \
>     --font LEGEND:7: --font UNIT:7: --font AXIS:5: -c CANVAS#000000 -c BACK#D8D8D8 \
>     DEF:DI=$RRDFDI:DI:AVERAGE \
>     CDEF:DIx=DI,8000,LT,DI,UNKN,IF \
>     AREA:DIx#FFDD44:\"\" \
>     LINE1.2:DIx#31B404:'Device Interrupts' \
>     GPRINT:DIx:MIN:'Min\:%6.0lf' \
>     GPRINT:DIx:AVERAGE:'Avg\:%6.0lf' \
>     GPRINT:DIx:MAX:'Max\:%6.0lf' \
>     GPRINT:DIx:LAST:'Cur\:%6.0lf\l'"